# Why is Happstack (toResponse) using text/plain per default?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I'm using `HStringTemplate` to render a very simple template using a data structure to fill in the "holes". The result of the template rendering is just a `String` I fed `toResponse` with.

Even though this rendered template is valid html happstack uses `text/plain` for `Content-Type`.

**What is the reason for this? Shouldn't `text/html` be default since it is a webserver?**
Do I really need to use `toResponseBS` and set `text/html` by myself?

Here is the code that creates the `ServerPart Response`

```
data Person = Person                                                                                                                                                                                                
    { name :: String                                                                                                                                                                                                
    , age ::Int                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    } deriving (Data, Typeable)                                                                                                                                                                                     

buildTemplate :: Person -> String -> FilePath -> ServerPart Response                                                                                                                                                
buildTemplate fields name template = do                                                                                                                                                                             
    unrendered <- liftIO $ readFile template                                                                                                                                                                        
    ok $ toResponse $ renderTemplate name fields unrendered                                                                                                                                                         

renderTemplate :: String -> Person -> String -> String                                                                                                                                                              
renderTemplate name fields unrendered = toString rendered                                                                                                                                                           
    where rendered = setAttribute name fields $ newSTMP unrendered
```

And here is the output from the webserver:

**Head**

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 09 Jan 2013 14:51:27 GMT
Server:Happstack/7.1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**Body**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Memlikweb</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, Richard!<h1>
        <p>Do you have 25 for me?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass Text.Html to toResponse the content type will be text/html.  You are passing a string, which toResponse takes to mean that the content type is plain text.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you.

Comment: Btw, I found out that supplying a `ByteString` also makes `toResponse` set `text/html` as default.

Answer (score 2):

The [happstack-hstringtemplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-hstringtemplate) package provides an instance for `ToMessage StringTemplate` which means if you import it and then use `toResponse` on the template without rendering it, it will do the right thing.